# C++ inline default constructors being removed in static library base class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, gcc, c++14

I'm wanting a sanity check about this behavior.

### libraryOne.a

```
class myBase
{
public:
   myBase();
   virtual ~myBase() {};

   myBase(const myBase& m) = default;
   myBase& operator=(const myBase& m)= default;

   myBase(myBase&& m)= default;
   myBase& operator=(myBase&& m)= default;

   virtual void ImplementMe() = 0;

   void AnotherFunction();

private:
   std::vector<SomeOtherClass> m_data;
};
```

### library2.a

```
class myDerived : public MyBase
{
public:
   myDerived();
   ~MyDerived();

   virtual void ImplementMe() override;
}
```

### Observation

Using the above scenario, Imagine the function in the base class, AnotherFunction(), has a for loop defined:

```
for(auto d : m_data)
```

I casually notice that the loop is making copies. Doh! So I fix it. Also we're not changing it, so I make it const.

```
for(const auto& d : m_data)
```

Suddenly my application which consists of one executable linking in LibraryOne.a and Library2.a fails to link. The change to the for loop was the only change. The linking error is atrocious, but i deduce that I have removed all usage of the copy constructor from libraryOne.a so the compiler stripped it out. "= default" created the constructor inline and from what I understand inline functions which are not used can be removed. When the application went to link, Library2.a no longer found the copy constructor for the base class and failed.

I solved the problem by defining the constructors in the .cpp file with the rest of the class definitions.

### Question

Is that the correct way to solve the problem? Is there a portable way to tell the compiler not to toss out the default constructors because a class may inherit from it in another library?

I'm using GCC 5.3.1 on ubuntu.

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

---

### UPDATE

It ended up being a link order error. This is my understanding of the gnu linker (you can, again, correct me if i'm wrong).

The linker processes static libraries from left to right during the link step. In my example it encountered libraryone.a first, and removed the constructors since they were not being used in the library. Then it hits library2.a which needed them and I got unresolved symbols.

When I put library2.a first, the linker will note the unresolved symbols and when it encounters then in libraryone.a it won't remove them.

This is now what I believe the problem was. I made my simple change and the linker said, "nope, don't need these anymore" and I got the errors.

I was in the process of putting together an example when I realized what was going on.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am pretty sure your observation is not correct. Compiler will not 'toss out' externally callable function from object file being generated. At most, it could be tossed out during LTO, it it ineed is never called in the whole app.

Comment: This sound like the case of the order of the arguments in link time. Try to reorder the object files in your linker command line.

Comment: Add `inline void test() {}` in `myBase`.  Do not call it in that library.  In `myDerived`, call `test()`.  Does it fail to link as well?  Or does it use the `test()` in the header file?    Second, note that copy constructors of classes intended to be inherited from are usually questionable, as they are slicing waiting to happen.

Comment: It ended up being a link order error but it manifested itself in such a strange way.

Comment: I second your analysis about link order.

Comment: You should move the update to an answer. This question is stuck on the *unanswered* page.

Comment: So, If you have a base class is both libraries and each library has a derived class for the base class defined in the other library then you can't build the app because there is no good link order?